# Find the recurrence equation for coloring a 1 by n chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

So the question asks me to find the number of ways H[n] to color a 1 by n chessboard with 3 colors - red, blue and white such that the number of red squares is even and number of blue squares is at least one. I am doing it in this way -

1.If the first square is white then the remaining n-1 squares can be colored in H[n-1] ways.

2.If the first square is red then another red will be needed in the n-1 remaining squares and the rest n-2 can be colored in H[n-2] ways. (i.e (n-1)*H[n-2])

3.And now is the problem with blue. If I put blue in the first square and say that the rest n-1 squares can be colored in H[n-1] ways that will be wrong as I already have a blue and may not need any more(while H[n-1] requires one blue at least). I thought of adding H'[n-1] to H[n] = H[n-1] + (n-1)*H[n-2] which gives H[n] = H[n-1] + (n-1)*H[n-2] + H'[n-1] where H'[n] is the number of ways to fill n squares with no blue squares(so H'[n] = (n-1)*H'[n-2] + H'[n-1]). So now I'm kind of really confused how to solve such an equation ->

H[n] = H[n-1] + (n-1)*H[n-2] + H'[n-1].

Comment: For the second case, you are overcounting since you are incorrectly applying significance to whether a square is colored red as a result of being the second guaranteed red square to match the first, or if it were red as a result of being a part of what remained.

Comment: As for a suggestion on how to correct this... So, you have $H[n]$ is the number of ways to color the chessboard with an *even* number of red squares and at least one blue square.  Try counting the very closely related $G[n]$ which counts the number of ways to color the chessboard with an *odd* number of red squares and at least one blue square.  If you know $H[n]$ for some value of $n$ then you should also know $G[n]$ for the same value of $n$... after all $H[n]+G[n]$ will equal the number of ways to color with at least one blue regardless of any conditions on white or red.